# Changing simple fill symbol to line fill symbol using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, symbology, classification

I have the following scale with different intervals in ArcMap:

[image]

I want to change it to:

[image]

The issue here is that I have to do this for many frames. Can I achieve it in arcpy?

```
import arcpy
lyrfile1 = "Some layer"
lyrfile1.symbology.classBreakValues = flatten([0, np.linspace(0,1, num=6).tolist()])
#Now I want something like this
#lyrfile1.symbology.firstinterval = "Line fill"
#lyrfile1.symbology.secondinterval = "Blue fill"
```

Comment: I've always done this by importing from a layer file that has the correct symbology using the tool Apply symbology from layer (management) https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006n000000, it's a lot less tedious than trying to generate a UniqueValuesRenderer https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componentHelp/index.html#//001200000sq5000000 using ArcObjects in python.

Comment: Or if it's the same layer you could change the symbology in one data frame then copy/paste it in the other data frame

Comment: If you're open to ArcGIS Pro you may have more luck using ArcPy with CIM access there.

Comment: @J.R How could I copy/paste the symbology? Could you please demonstrate it or share a link?

Comment: @MichaelStimson This seems promising. I will try this as well. Thanks

Comment: An extra hack that might help is sys.argv[0] which contains the full path to the python script being executed, keep the layer file in the same folder and you can avoid hard paths. From memory the layer file has to be linked to data to work properly however you can also add the layer, valid or not, from the layer file and reset the data source https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/ using the function replaceDataSource.

Comment: @G.S.J I mean copiing the whole layer, not just symbology...

Answer (score 2):

If you read the help file for graduated symbols the first paragraph under the [discussion](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/analyze/arcpy-mapping/graduatedsymbolssymbology-class.htm) section states there is no mechanism for changing a symbol in ArcMap, you need to apply an existing symbology to the entire layer, you cannot drill down to a single symbol and tweak it. As suggested by @MichaelStimson use the apply symbology tool.